# executing a Python script from PHP, timing issues?

Tags: php, python

I think I have some timer that is expiring before my script is complete.  I found this nice tutorial.  [How to execute python script from php and show output on browser](http://blog.idealmind.com.br/desenvolvimento-web/php/how-to-execute-python-script-from-php-and-show-output-on-browser/).  And it starts to work, but stops printing my debug messages from the script before it completes.

My PHP Code:

```
<?php

$param1 = '"romAudit"';
$param2 = '"Nintendo Entertainment System"';
$param3 = "third";

$command = "python scripts/arcade_functions.py";
$command .= " $param1 $param2";

 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />';
echo "<style type='text/css'>
 body{
 background:#000;
 color: #7FFF00;
 font-family:'Lucida Console',sans-serif !important;
 font-size: 12px;
 }
 </style>";



$pid = popen( $command,"r");

echo "<body><pre>";
while( !feof( $pid ) )
{
 echo fread($pid, 256);
 flush();
 ob_flush();
 echo "<script>window.scrollTo(0,99999);</script>";
 usleep(100000);
}
pclose($pid);

echo "</pre><script>window.scrollTo(0,99999);</script>";
echo "<br /><br />Script Complete<br /><br />";
?>
```

output from windows command prompt:

```
C:\Arcade\www\scripts>python arcade_functions.py "romAudit" "Nintendo Entertainment System"
Arguments passed: romAudit Nintendo Entertainment System
Executing audit of Nintendo Entertainment System now

Extracting system XML database ...
Extraction Complete.

Creating a list of the files in the directory of ROM Path...
Directory Listing Complete

Determining which ROMs match the XML database ...
Found Directory: _Not In Database , Sub-Directories will not be audited
Matching Complete

Attempting to create "_Not In Database" directory
ERROR directory Y:\ROMS\Nintendo Entertainment System\_Not In Database, exists

Moving unmatched ROMs to "_Not In Database" directory ...
Moving complete, check Y:\ROMS\Nintendo Entertainment System\_Not In Database for un-matched ROMs

found 791 out of 791 ROMs

C:\Arcade\www\scripts>
```

I think there is some timer or something that is killing the script before it completes. It takes around 2.5 seconds to complete in the windows command prompt.

I know the script is not completing outside of PHP because I create a log file and write everything to at at the end of the python function.

Python Script (I'm still learning, I removed some other functions that don't apply to fit within the character limit):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Script Python Example

from xml.dom import minidom
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import os, re, shutil, sys

'''
    Create the Log Files directories first by uncommenting the "createLogDirs()", only run this once
    Set all paths in the path sections below
'''

rlPath = 'C:\\Arcade\\RocketLauncher\\' #set your RocketLauncher Path here
hsPath = 'C:\\Arcade\\FrontEnds\\HyperSpin\\' #set your HyperSpin Path here
romPath = 'Y:\\ROMS\\'  #set your ROM Path here
downloadPath = "C:\\Users\\Ben\\Downloads\\EmuMovies\\" #EmuMovies Download Path
logFiles = 'C:\\Arcade\\Logs\\' #Where to create and put the log files

param1 = sys.argv[1]
param2 = sys.argv[2]

print('Arguments passed:', param1, param2)


def databaseGameExtraction(xml):
    print('Extracting system XML database ...')
    xmldoc = minidom.parse(xml)
    systemName = [xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('listname')[0].childNodes[0].data]
    games = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('game')
    roms = []
    for game in games:
        romKey = game.attributes['name']
        roms.append(romKey.value)
    print('Extraction Complete.',"\n")
    return roms, systemName

def romsAvailable(path):
    print('Creating a list of the files in the directory of ROM Path...')
    romsList = os.listdir(path)
    print('Directory Listing Complete',"\n")
    return romsList

def romAudit(system):
    print('Executing ROM audit of', system, 'now', '\n')
    xmlToAudit = hsPath + 'Databases' + '\\' + system + '\\' + system + '.xml'
    if os.path.isfile(xmlToAudit):
        roms, systemName = databaseGameExtraction(xmlToAudit)
        romsList = romsAvailable(romPath + system)
        output = []
        print('Determining which ROMs match the XML database ...')
        for newList in romsList:
            if os.path.isdir(romPath + system + '\\' + newList):
                print('Found Directory:', newList, ', Sub-Directories will not be audited')
            else:
                newRoms = os.path.splitext(newList)
                output.append(newRoms)
        inDatabase = []
        notInDatabase = []
        for value in output:
            if value[0] in roms:
                inDatabase.append(value)
            else:
                notInDatabase.append(value)
        print('Matching Complete', "\n")
        notInDatabasePath = romPath + system + '\\' + '_Not In Database'
        print('Attempting to create "_Not In Database" directory')
        try:
            os.makedirs(notInDatabasePath)
        except:
            print('ERROR directory ' + notInDatabasePath + ', exists \n')
        print('Moving unmatched ROMs to "_Not In Database" directory ...')
        for extra in notInDatabase:  # Moves the ROMs that are not in the database
            dst = notInDatabasePath + '\\' + extra[0] + extra[1]
            src = romPath + system + '\\' + extra[0] + extra[1]
            try:
                # print(src)
                # print(dst)
                shutil.move(src, dst)
            except:
                errorMessage = 'error copying ' + '"' + extra[0] + extra[1] + '"' + '\n'
                file = open(logFiles + system + ' romAuditError.txt', 'a')
                errorlog = errorMessage
                file.write(errorlog)
                file.close()
        print('Moving complete, check', notInDatabasePath, 'for un-matched ROMs', "\n")
        print('found ' + str(len(inDatabase)) + ' out of ' + str(len(roms)) + ' ROMs')
    else:
        print('error' + system + 'not a valid XML File')

    if os.path.isfile(logFiles + 'Have\\' + system + ' ROM have.txt'):
        os.remove(logFiles + 'Have\\' + system + ' ROM have.txt')
    if os.path.isfile(logFiles + 'Missing\\' + system + ' ROM missing.txt'):
        os.remove(logFiles + 'Missing\\' + system + ' ROM missing.txt')
    have = []
    for game in inDatabase:
        rom = game[0] + '\n'
        have.append(game[0])
        file = open(logFiles + 'Have\\' + system + ' ROM have.txt', 'a')
        file.write(rom)
        file.close()
    missing = []
    for rom in roms:
        if rom not in have:
            missing.append(rom)
            print(rom, "NOT found")
    for miss in missing:
        output = miss + '\n'
        file = open(logFiles + 'Missing\\' + system + ' ROM missing.txt', 'a')
        file.write(output)
        file.close()



if param1 == 'romAudit':
    romAudit(param2)
else:
    print(param1, 'or', param2, 'is not valid')
```

PHP Output (copied from the Chrome Browser):

```
Arguments passed: romAudit Nintendo Entertainment System
Executing ROM audit of Nintendo Entertainment System now 

Extracting system XML database ...
Extraction Complete. 

Creating a list of the files in the directory of ROM Path...


Script Complete
```

Comment: Can you post the Python script?

Comment: And also the php output?

Comment: Could your script be failing to access the ROM path and so return nothing?

Comment: @Steve, I don't think the script is the issue since it works from the Windows command prompt with the same parameters passed.

Comment: Sorry I just meant does your php localhost have the same folder access as the Windows command prompt?

Comment: You may be onto something, I didn't configure anything in the PHP conf file.  However I cannot think of how that would matter since PHP is just executing the python script.  Python has all rights and privileges available to run the commands contained within the script.  I'm no Python/HTTP/PHP expert, I just figured I'd try to learn, so some of the more advanced stuff is still a bit foreign.

Comment: It was just that the Windows command prompt output already seemed to have things that didn't look too happy as in:     Attempting to create "_Not In Database" directory
ERROR directory Y:\ROMS\Nintendo Entertainment System\_Not In Database, exists

Comment: @Steve, thanks I think you're right about the folder access by PHP.  I changed the ROM path to a local value (C:\ROMs) and the script completed.  There must be some type of configuration in PHP not allowing this.  I even tried the windows version of symbolic link (mklink /D .....), but the script still failed, I guess it knows that it's a symbolic link.  I'll figure something else out.  Thanks all

Comment: @BenElder - maybe worth posting as a separate question regarding file permissions to attract more appropriate answers. Time to dig out an old XP box and trash the OS and replace it with Crunchbang Linux - now replaced but was easy to set up http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=38916 and its derivative   https://www.bunsenlabs.org/  - good use for an old box!

Comment: `python scripts/arcade_functions.py` space in the path? Not sure if I am reading that correctly but it might be an issue if there is one.

Comment: `os.makedirs(notInDatabasePath)` are you able to add ChMod 0777 like in php? http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php  - sorry I am not really that up on Python.